# Crear Columna a Partir de la Condición de Otras dos Columnas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, google-colab

Tengo el siguiente problema, por un lado tengo un data Frame con dos columnas, el nombre de las personas y las tecnologías que manejan:

```
import pandas as pd
ipmort numpy as np    
censo = pd.DataFrame({"Nombre":["Uriel","Ricardo","Rodrigo","Arion"], "Tec":[("Sas, Python"),("Python, Pyspark"),("Python, Tableau"),("Excel")]})
censo.head()
```

La salida es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego tengo otro dataframe que tiene otras dos columnas: solicitudes y tecnología que requiere esa solicitud:

```
tec = pd.DataFrame({"Solicitud":["001","002","003","004"], "Tec":["Python","Sas","Tableau","Excel"]})
tec.head()
```

Cuya salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que requiero conseguir es crear una columna llamada "Asignación" en la cual aparezca el nombre de la persona del primer dataframe que haga mejor fit con las tecnología que piden en la solicitud.

Intente con una sintaxys en numpy, pero no quede ni cerca de lo que necesito:

```
tec["Asignación"] = np.where((tec['Tec'] == censo["Tec"]),1,0)
tec
```

Alguna idea de que pudiera hacer para solucionar este problema?

De antemano. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Como piensas sacar el `fit`?? Si no hay ningún otro valor para tomar en cuenta

Comment: Por ejemplo en la solicitud "004" que piden alguien que conozca "Excel" , quien debería aparecer en la columna que quiero crear de "Asignación" pues es el único con ese skill es "Arion".

Comment: y para el caso de python?? tienes a 3 personas, ¿a cual elijes?

Comment: Para nosotros como humanos es claro que la asignación en el ejemplo debería de ser 001 Ricardo, 002 Uriel, 003 Rodrigo y 004 Arion. Pues a ojo se ve que manejan las tecnologías requeridas en cada solicitud y no dejas a nadie fuera.  Sin embargo, en el data set completo donde habrá más personas y más tecnologías lo que buscaría es que fueran FIFO, primeras entradas , primeras salidas, es decir que si tengo la 001 esa es prioritaria y busco al primer elemento del censo que cuente con el Skill.

Comment: En ese caso bastaría con ordenar de forma descendente el DataFrame y elegir el primero

Comment: ¿Cada nombre debe ser utilizado o puede haber repetidos? Por ejemplo, si buscamos únicamente la primera coincidencia entonces sería Uriel, Uriel, Rodrigo, Arion

Comment: No puede haber repetidos, conforme al orden de solicitud si se acaban personas con ese skill, deberia mostrar vacio.